# How to set Quiet option for Elastic Search when doing a Bulk Insert?

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk

I can do this:

```
curl -s -XPOST  1.2.3.4:9200/my_index/my_index_type/_bulk  -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" --data-binary  @/home/modified.json
```

But this fails:

```
curl -s -XPOST  1.2.3.4:9200/my_index/my_index_type/_bulk  -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" --data-binary  @/home/modified.json --quiet
```

How to set 'quiet'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to Disallows non-log STDOUT output with `--quiet`. Let's try this way-

```
curl -s --quiet -XPOST 1.2.3.4:9200/my_index/my_index_type/_bulk -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" --data-binary  @/home/modified.json
```

According to the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/3.3/quiet.html) of `--quiet`,

> This flag **must come before** any command.

If it doesn't do the job then you can use the `-o` switch and send the output to `dev/null` instead of using `--quiet`

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -XPOST 1.2.3.4:9200/my_index/my_index_type/_bulk -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" --data-binary  @/home/modified.json
```

Comment: @Joe glad it helps you somehow :)